# How to make SHAP summary_plot only for selected features from list in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I try to make SHAP summary plot in Python only for selected features from my ML model.

Generally we can make SHAP summary plot like below:

```
import shap

model = clf
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

But how can I do that only for selected features from X_test, for example for features from list like: `my_list = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by excluding features from the inputs you send summary_plot as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shap
shap.initjs()

model = clf
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X_test)

features_list = ['col1','col13','col25']
shap_values_fl = pd.DataFrame(shap_values)
shap_values_fl = shap_values_fl[features_list]
X_test_fl = X_test[features_list]

shap.summary_plot(np.array(shap_values_fl), X_test_fl)
```